# Connect to Server in SMSS 2017 on Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication, virtual-machine

Need some help understanding how to connect to Sql Management Server Studios 2017 from my Azure Virtual Machine.

I thought I just enter my Computer (VM-computer name) in server name, see picture below, but I get the error saying: The server was not found or is not accesible. Do I need to configure it to allow remote access? Am lost and have tried googling without result, any easy step-by-step guides?

[pic of login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JLQF.png)

Comment: Do you mean you install SSMS 2017 on Azure VM, and you can't connect to Azure SQL server or the SQL you install on your Azure VM?

Comment: Correct, I installed SSMS 2017 on Azure VM and want to connect to the SQL(SSMS2017) I installed on the VM.

Comment: In the same VM?

Comment: Yes, 
In the VM I installed I want to have my SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your server name in "servername" or . and the connect. If still not connecting do check whether it is named instances running in SQL Server Configuration Manager. If it is running with named instance you need to provide "Servername\namedinstancename" in server name

Comment: It didn't work to just put computer name in "servername". 

How do I see the namedinstancename in Server Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have any sql installed, only the SSMS..........rookie move.